# English complement

Tags: grammar

I have this sentence below:

> I can picture him now, sitting at his desk pilled high with manuscripts and reference books, leaning back in his chair and looking out of the window while a cigarette burned between his fingers.

The question is for the part of the sentence from 'sitting ...'. What is this structure? Is it a complement of the sentence? If the answer is positive, could you guys please link me to the document/documents for references?

Comment: Hello, I meant 'What is this structure?'. It was a typo, and I have updated it.

Comment: No, not a complement but a depictive adjunct.